# Breakpoints in Safari dev tools get enabled automatically

Tags: safari, breakpoints, safari-web-inspector

Each time I load a page with Safari dev tools opened (no matter which tab), some breakpoints get triggered and I get redirected to the Sources tab with the message "Debugger Paused". 
The problem is that I didn't set any breakpoints, at least, intentionally, and these redirects don't let me review the source code or load webpages properly. 
Even if I disable them, they get re-enabled as soon as I reload the page. I'm failing to understand why this happens.

I see two breakpoints in the Sources tab: All Exceptions and Uncaught Exceptions, but they don't seem to be enabled. 
Unfortunately, I couldn't find how to disable the debugger or locate those exceptions. There are no options to do that in the context menu if I right-click the "Debugger Paused" message, disabled exceptions in the Sources tab or Safari settings. 
Has anybody come across similar issues or know how to fix that behavior? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Safari 13.1
macOS 10.15.4

[Here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGtim.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You click "+" next to the Breakpoints, then you click All Requests. And then it will appear in the list and is enabled by default. You click disable - VIOLA! See the attached image.

[image]